# WPF Button Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, button, binding, grid

I want to make a Button Tablet, which consists of 1 .. 10 Buttons.

Now I have a grid, which has rows and colums, lets say 2 columns, 5 rows,
but this is not very dymamical.

I have some xml-source which specifies which and how much buttons are in 
that grid, how they should look like, row and column position.

How can I dynamically insert buttons at positions?

In the TabletViewModel I have a collection of ButtonViewModels
and it is the DataContext for the TabletView (the Grid)

The ButtonViewModel holds the text, image-filename, row and column of the buttons
and is the DataContext for one Button.

I thought of something like the itemsource Binding, but I can't figure out
how to do this Binding with a grid and buttons. (Dynamic GridView?)

How can i do this? Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or maybe consider using ItemsControl with WrapPanel

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(assuming x:Name="myGrid" in markup)

// add rows to grid (it's the same deal for columns too)
 for (int row=0;row < numRows; row++)
 {
 myGrid=RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
 }

(I'd be interested to see if there is a slicker way of doing this bit. )


// Stick a control in intended location

b = new Button();

myGrid.Children.Add(b);
 Grid.SetRow(b,1); // 2nd row
 Grid.SetColumn(b,3); // 4th column
 Grid.SetColumnSpan(b,2);
```

Comment: Thank you! But isn't there a way i can use Bindings, i.e. i want to bind the grid to my TabletViewModel to get this done. And i want to bind an ICommand published by the top ViewModel as Click Handler for each Button. It gets a ButtonViewModel as context, which is used for handling the ClickEvent.